# Svelte v3 programmatically create a component with props and event listeners

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Is it possible to create a component and programmatically attach event listeners to it?

I know that this is easily possible for props using `<svelte:component/>` by spreading with `{ ...props }`. I wonder if something similar can be achieved to attach event listeners.

E.g., in the following example I would like to programmatically attach `on:message` to `A` and `on:count` to `B`:

```
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import A from './A.svelte';
    import B from './B.svelte';

    let message = 'Hi there ';
    let count = 0;

    const components = [{
        component: A,
        props: { message },
        listeners: { message: (m) => { console.log(`They say "${m}"`); } }
    }, {
        component: B,
        props: { count },
        listeners: { click: () => { count++; } }
    }];
</script>

{#each components as component}
    <div><svelte:component this={component.component} { ...component.props }/></div>
{/each}

<div>
    <p>They say "{message}"!</p>
    <p>They clicked {count} times!</p>
</div>

<!-- A.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    export let message = '';
    function changeHandler(e) { dispatch('message', message); }
</script>

<input on:change={changeHandler} on:value={message} value={message} />

<!-- B.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    export let count = 0;
    function clickHandler() { dispatch('count', count); }
</script>

<button on:click={clickHandler}>Click me</button>
```

Here's a live demo: https://svelte.dev/repl/af1bd30ab75b43f19b72a306340b7282?version=3.18.2

I.e., I am hoping there's a way to expand the `components` array to

```
<A message={message} on:message={e => { message = e.detail; }}/>
<B count={count} on:count={e => { count = e.detail; }}/>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `$on`to dynamically register a listener on component events.

In your usecase, you can use this component :

*ComponentEvent.svelte*

```html
<svelte:component this={component.component} { ...component.props } bind:this={instance}/>

<script>
  export let component;

    let instance;
    
    $: if (instance && component.listeners) {
        for (let [key, listener] of Object.entries(component.listeners)) {
            instance.$on(key, listener);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and replace in you App.svelte the each loop with :

```html
{#each components as component}
    <ComponentEvent {component}/>
{/each}
```

see this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b495a6d61e64d0cabdb3657f100837c?version=3.18.2)

Comment: Also https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component

Comment: great answer. how can i pass data to event listener?

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically attach listeners, no - don't forget Svelte is a compiled language, it does all the heavy lifting at compile time, so things need to be known in advance.

What I've done for dynamic listeners is to fire a single known event, and then have the event detail contain differential logic, such as event names, etc. As in the following:

```
// SomeComponent.svelte
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()

  dispatch('component-event', { name: 'alert', value: 'oh noes' })
  dispatch('component-event', { name: 'log', value: 'some message' })
</script>
```

```
// App.svelte
<svelte:component this={someComponent} on:component-event={e => handleEvent(e)} />

<script>
  function handleEvent ({ detail }) {
    const { name, value } = detail
    if (name === 'alert') { alert(value) }
    if (name === 'log') { console.log(value) }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks for sharing. Aside, I am not entirely sure why it should technically not be possible to dynamically attach event listeners when it's possible to dynamically attach props. Maybe this is just a limitation of the current API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can programmatically attach them like you're looking for but you can pass a function, or a callback in the object and account for each of the potential dispatched events in the svelte:component tag like this:

```
<svelte:component
    this={component.component}
    { ...component.props }
    on:message={ component.function}
    on:count={ component.function}
/>
```

Here's a working example in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8d6986c6f08648269d68df38ec108667?version=3.18.2) that shows both an arrow function in the object and a callback(if a more meaty function is needed) the callback still gets the event detail.

I don't think anything happens if the dispatched event is not present in a component, but if you needed a single component to dispatch multiple events you would need something else.

Comment: This approach requires one to know in advance what the callbacks are and cover all of them. This is fine in my toy demo but I am actually looking for a solution that doesn't require the event names to be known upfront.

Comment: I don't think the listeners can be attached without the on: directive using just Svelte, props work without a directive so spreading them without one makes sense.